# MongdDB: Combining query results of two collections as one

Tags: mongodb

There are two collections (view and click) like following:

```
# View collection
_id                         publisher_id    created_at
617f8ea98e0f54f05e10e796        1           2021-11-01T00:00:00.000Z
617f8eab8e0f54f05e10e798        1           2021-11-01T00:00:00.000Z
617f8eac8e0f54f05e10e79a        1           2021-11-01T00:00:00.000Z
617f90cea187d30ebbecdee9        2           2021-11-01T00:00:00.000Z

# Click collection
_id                         publisher_id    created_at
617f8ea98e0f54f05e10e796        1           2021-11-01T00:00:00.000Z
617f8eab8e0f54f05e10e798        2           2021-11-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

How can I get the following expected results with one query?
(or)
What is the best way for the following expected results?

```
# Expected For Publisher ID(1)  
_id         view_count  click_count
2021/11/1   3           1
        
# Expected For Publisher ID(2)      
_id         view_count  click_count
2021/11/1   1           1
```

Currently, I am using 2 queries for both collections and combining results as one in code.

#### For View

```
db.view.aggregate([
    /*FirstStage*/
    {
        $match:
            {
                "$and":
                    [
                        {
                            "publisher_id": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "created_at": {$gte: new ISODate("2021-11-01"), $lt: new ISODate("2021-11-28")}
                        }
                    ]
            }
    },
    /*SecondStage*/
    {
        $group:
            {
                _id: {$dateToString: {format: '%Y/%m/%d', date: "$created_at"}},
                count: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
    }
])
```

#### For Click

```
db.click.aggregate([
    /*FirstStage*/
    {
        $match:
            {
                "$and":
                    [
                        {
                            "publisher_id": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "created_at": {$gte: new ISODate("2021-11-01"), $lt: new ISODate("2021-11-28")}
                        }
                    ]
            }
    },
    /*SecondStage*/
    {
        $group:
            {
                _id: {$dateToString: {format: '%Y/%m/%d', date: "$created_at"}},
                count: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
    }
])
```

Comment: You can try using the `$unionWIth` aggregation stage.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are querying two different collections there is no "good" way to merge this into one query, the only way I can think of is using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/), where the first stage is the "normal" one, and the other stage starts with a `$lookup` from the other collection.

This approach does add overhead, which is why I recommend to just keep doing the merge in code, however for the sake of answering here is a sample:

```
db.view.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      views: [
        {
          $match: {
            "$and": [
              {
                "publisher_id": 1
              },
              {
                "created_at": {
                  $gte: ISODate("2021-11-01"),
                  $lt: ISODate("2021-11-28")
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        
      ],
      clicks: [
        {
          $limit: 1
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "click",
            let: {},
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  "$and": [
                    {
                      "publisher_id": 1
                    },
                    {
                      "created_at": {
                        $gte: ISODate("2021-11-01"),
                        $lt: ISODate("2021-11-28")
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              
            ],
            as: "clicks"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$clicks"
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$clicks"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      merged: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$views",
          "$clicks"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$merged"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y/%m/%d",
          date: "$merged.created_at"
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aD5kOEVKloF)